# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Selecting Parent Child recursion from Single Table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a table called categories where the table structure and data is

```
id | parent_id | name
------------------------
1  | 0         | Computers    // parent
2  | 0         | TV           // parent
4  | 1         | Motherboards // child - to - id(1)
5  | 4         | Mercury
6  | 5         | Mecrury XXX
7  | 6         | Mecrury YYY
```

(Where **parent_id** is **id** of another row)

Show how can i get parent/child results using **Rails3 Activerecord query interface**. (Or any other solution).

If i search for Computer how can i get all the childs -> super child under that parent category.

```
Example Result will - Computers -> Motherboards -> Mercury XXX -> Mercury YYY
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [awesome nested set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) gem.

It allows you to call something like this to get all descendant nodes:

```
Node.root.self_and_descendants
```

The [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) seems good as well, though I haven't used it myself.

Both gems will require a migration of your data but it's for the better, as using just a parent_id for navigating child nodes isn't the most efficient.